ui files made with qt creator have invalid syntax for qgis
I made a UI in QT Creator that only has QDialogButtonBox:

When I save it out, the .ui file looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>ProjectDialogBase</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="ProjectDialogBase">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>184</width>
    <height>47</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Settings</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="button_box">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>-10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>181</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Orientation::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="standardButtons">
    <set>QDialogButtonBox::StandardButton::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::StandardButton::Ok</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>button_box</sender>
   <signal>rejected()</signal>
   <receiver>ProjectDialogBase</receiver>
   <slot>reject()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>button_box</sender>
   <signal>accepted()</signal>
   <receiver>ProjectDialogBase</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>

When I zip it up and try to import it into QGIS in a plugin, the file fails to compile:
  File "/home/username/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/sync/interfaces/settings_dialogue.py", line 8, in 
    FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'settings_dialogue.ui'))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/PyQt/uic/__init__.py", line 36, in __loadUiType
    return __PyQtLoadUiType(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt5/uic/__init__.py", line 207, in loadUiType
    exec(code_string.getvalue(), ui_globals)
  File "", line 10
    self.button_box.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Qt::Orientation::Horizontal)
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Reverting the changes in the file shows that all the enum values were changed from Qt::Horizontal to Qt::Orientation::Horizontal and QDialogButtonBox::Cancel to QDialogButtonBox::StandardButton::Cancel. Was there an update to QT Creator that made the two incompatible? They're both installed through flatpak, QGIS is 3.38.3 and QT Creator is 14.0.2.

The changed happened a few versions ago for Qt Designer (and therefore the parts of Creator using its elements), which introduced full namespaces for all enums, in order to make it full compliant with the same aspect in Python (IIRC). The latest PyQt versions should be able to cope with that, so the problem may be that QGIS doesn't have a properly updated pyuic.

@musicamante Interesting, thank you! Looks like pyqt5 has a note on enums. Now to figure out where to report it...

Posted an issue: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/59310

Note that the change is fundamentally only about the Python syntax, and the change was actually introduced since [Py]Qt6 and ported back in later PyQt5 versions as well (while keeping backward compatibility). The difference is that PyQt still supported the "old style" syntax as well for any Qt5 release, but the full namespaces were introduced and became mandatory since PyQt6, while PySide (the "official" Python bindings) officially allowed the new syntax only since PySide6 and still allow a "permissive" (and somehow confusing/inconsistent) syntax right now.

Yet, AFAIK, what you're facing is just about the relation between the uic module of PyQt and the changes introduced in the latest official Qt releases (which include Qt Designer, what actually outputs the ui files). Qt decided to make enums more "namespace aware" following the changes "suggested" by PyQt (while PySide is the official Python binding of Qt, it's still somehow "based" on the unofficial PyQt bindings). The inconsistency is maddening yet understandable: one of the few drawbacks of open source trying to meet incompatibility (license, popularity, efficiency, etc.).

@musicamante Thanks for all that info, it is maddening! Do you know which version of qt creator I should use? I might have to install through apt since flatpak makes installing old versions... unintuitive

Unfortunately, no, and I actually don't use Creator (I only use Designer). The change was introduced in the last year, most certainly since the infamous Qt6.7, so you should eventually check for Creator/Designer versions released prior to that version. Note that, AFAIK, the latest PyQt6 releases should work fine with that, so if you have it installed and you're skilled enough, you may check the differences in the uic module and fix the PyQt5 version (I assume you have the latest PyQt5, though, haven't you?).

@musicamante Flatpak shows org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15-23.08, digging a few layers deeper it looks like QT 5.15.11

I don't have a lot of experience with sandbox-based package management (I understand the needs on which they were created and I may agree with the concerns they're based upon, but, simply put, I just hate them), so I'm not even sure that the PyQt you're using is the same QGIS is using. In any case, the only way to be sure about the Qt version is by importing QT_VERSION_STR from the script you're using. But, if it's really using the sandboxed package, then things get ugly (and that's one of the reasons for which I hate these systems).

In any case, both assuming that the sandboxed and/or sandboxed versions do not comply with the new syntax, I believe you're left with only two options: 1. use a previous version of Creator/Designer that doesn't use the full namespaces; 2. implement a fallback mechanism (in case uic functions fail) that will eventually parse the UI file (possibly through XML node management), and replace all instances of <class>::<namespace>::<enum> with <class>::<enum> before trying to rebuild the UI based on the raw contents (maybe using a buffer interface?).

@musicamante Thanks for the tip on that string, qgis is running 5.15.10. If you want to turn that into an answer I'll accept it because I think some extra processing is the easiest solution for now, thankfully my interface is pretty simple so I can do a regex replace on (Q\w+?)::\w+?::(\w+) -> $1::$2.

Since you came out with that, and it seems to work for you, I'd suggest you to use the "Answer your question" button, summarize what discussed above and provide a basic MRE of its usage.

@musicamante Thanks for all the help! I've added my answer, obviously feel free to edit if I missed anything ️

Thanks to some discussion with musicamante I have a better idea what's going on:

The changed happened a few versions ago for Qt Designer (and therefore the parts of Creator using its elements), which introduced full namespaces for all enums, in order to make it full compliant with the same aspect in Python (IIRC). The latest PyQt versions should be able to cope with that, so the problem may be that QGIS doesn't have a properly updated pyuic.

Printing QT_VERSION_STR inside qgis's python console (Plugins > Python Console) shows 5.15.10, so at this point it's a few years old:
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
print(QT_VERSION_STR)
5.15.10

The easiest solution without downgrading versions (flatpak makes that a little difficult) was to use VSCode's find text feature with (Q\w+?)::\w+?::(\w+) and replace it with $1::$2. My ui files are small so it's easy to verify that the replacement was correct.
